# Exception propagation: When should I catch exceptions?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, exceptions

MethodA calls an MethodB which in turn calls MethodC.

There is NO exception handling in MethodB or MethodC. But there is exception handling in MethodA.

In MethodC an exception occurs.

Now, that exception is bubbling up to MethodA, which handles it appropriately.

What is wrong with this?

In my mind, at some point a caller will execute MethodB or MethodC, and when exceptions do occur in those methods, what will be gained from handling exceptions inside those methods, which essentially is just a try/catch/finally block instead of just let them bubble up to the callee?

The statement or consensus around exception handling is to throw when execution cannot continue due to just that - an exception. I get that. But why not catch the exception further up the chain instead of having try/catch blocks all the way down.

I understand it when you need to free up resources. That's a different matter entirely.

Comment: Why do you think the consensus is to have a chain of pass through catches?

Comment: With a good IDE and a proper coding style, you can know that some exception can be thrown when a method is called. Handle it or allow it to be propagated is the decision of the caller. I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: If a method can't handle the exception, and is merely rethrowing it, I would say that is a code smell. If a method can't handle the exception, and doesn't need to do anything else when an exception is thrown then there is no need for a `try-catch` block at all.

Comment: "What is wrong with this ?" : nothing

Comment: Take for instance a DB call. The SQL call fails and the exception bubbles up until it is handled and logged. At this point, I feel the logging would be worthless because I no longer have the parameters that *caused* it to fail. Imagine catching and logging at the level where the exception is thrown. Your investigation of the logged exception becomes almost too easy. Once you have logged the exception, set a flag in it's IDictionary Data property. Then `throw` (NOT `throw(exception)`) the exception back up. Any catch blocks can check this flag using `when` filters to prevent multiple logging.

Comment: Pass-through catching (that doesn't wrap exceptions in different types or anything like that) defeats the whole purpose of exceptions. Exception throwing is a complex mechanism, and it was built intentionally. If pass-through catches were the intended use case, then all you would need is to implement a `Result<T>` type (a type that either stores a result of a computation, or an error), and return it from your otherwise throwing functions. Propagating an error up the stack would entail reading every return value, checking if its an error, and returning an error if so.

Comment: @Alexander. I believe you are responding to my comment? Wouldn't your implementation of `Result<T>` require catching the error in the first place? Or am I missing something. Also, I'm not clear on if *"propagating an error up the stack"* is referring to my concept or yours.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Nope, I was addressing OP, along the same lines as what Caleth said. "Wouldn't your implementation of Result<T> require catching the error in the first place?" Nope, in this parallel universe, there is no `throw`, `catch` or exceptions at all. Just an error object (similar to an exception, storing diagnostic info about the error) that is wrapped into a `Result<T>` and returned. If the intention was to have a usage pattern like "have a chain of pass through catches", then `Result<T>` is all that would be needed to be implemented, which is just an ordinary class whose objects ...

Comment: @ShaiCohen ... are returned, just like any other values. The whole point of exception mechanisms is to have this "bubbling up" behaviour that lets exceptions implicitly propagate up until the appropriate layer catches and handles it. That's a much more complicated usage pattern, which requires much more runtime machinery. But it was implemented anyway, which strongly suggests that the "have a chain of pass through catches" usage pattern was not the intended error handling pattern.

Comment: @Alexander To be noted that that's exactly why Java checked exceptions suck hard. They force you to handle them at all levels by either using a `catch` or adding a `throws` statement. If the point of the exceptions is to allow them to be ignored in the middle layers between the thrower and the catcher, then forcing those layers to acknowledge them is counter productive since a `throws` clause is the same as having a catch-and-re throw every time, it still forces you to change all layers if, for example, the exception thrown/caught is changed.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yeah, but I've seen a pretty popular movement to moving to unchecked exceptions everywhere around me, so I didn't even consider this :p Yeah, it seems to me that it defeats much of the point of exceptions.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

As a general principle, don't catch exceptions unless you know what to do with them.  If MethodC throws an exception, but MethodB has no useful way to handle it, then it should allow the exception to propagate up to MethodA.

The only reasons why a method should have a catch and rethrow mechanism are:

- You want to convert one exception to a different one that is more meaningful to the caller above.
- You want to add extra information to the exception.
- You need a catch clause to clean up resources that would be leaked without one.

Otherwise, catching exceptions at the wrong level tends to result in code that silently fails without providing any useful feedback to the calling code (and ultimately the user of the software).  The alternative of catching an exception and then immediately rethrowing it is pointless.

Comment: I would also add "cleaning up resources" as another reason to catch and then rethrow.

Comment: @GregBurghardt if your language has something akin to `try ... finally ...`, then use that, not catch & rethrow

Comment: "catching an exception and then immediately rethrowing it is pointless" Depending on the language and how you go about this it can be actively harmful to the codebase.  Often people attempting this remove a lot of information about the exception such as the original stacktrace.  I've dealt with code where the caller gets an exception that is completely misleading as to what happened and where.

Comment: `You want to convert one exception to a different one` or just turning the checked one into a non-checked.

Comment: "don't catch exceptions unless you know what to do with them". That sounds reasonable on first glance, but causes problems later on. What you're doing here is leaking implementation details to your callers. Imagine that you're using a particular ORM in your implementation to load data. If you don't catch that ORM's specific exceptions but just let them bubble up, you cannot replace your data layer without breaking compatibility with existing users. That's one of the more obvious cases, but it can get quite insidious and is hard to catch.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't throw away the original exception information. Make sure it is wrapped in the new exception so it is available to whoever ends up debugging some issue months or years don't the road. There's nothing like the joy of debugging an application that uses a framework whose guiding principle was "the users of this are too stupid to be trusted with complicated things like exceptions" and not being able to see anything other than some generic exception from 5 layers above the true, original problem.

Comment: @Voo In your example you _do_ know what to do with it. Wrap it in a documented exception specific to your code, e.g. `LoadDataException` and **include the original exception details** according to your language features, so that future maintainers are able to see the root cause without having to attach a debugger and figure out how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Caleth Or even better, a dedicated resource cleanup mechanism. Python has context managers. C# has `IDisposable` with `using`. Java has `AutoCloseable` with `try`-with-resources.

Comment: @Voo You seem to have missed the "You want to convert one exception to a different one that is more meaningful to the caller above" reason for catch/rethrow scenarios.

Comment: @Voo And that's where you get into dependency inversion. If *you* own the data provider, you should wrap the exception with something meaningful within the context of your library/method. If the provider is owned by the invoker, the invoker needs to handle it (whether through exception propagation, callbacks or something else depends on the situation). The invoker should never have to deal with *your* implementation details, but the same way, you shouldn't have to deal with the invoker's.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess if you interpret meaningful that way. Generally you hide useful information in an inner exception. But it also means you basically have to catch almost all exceptions lower layers of your library throw and wrap them (with the exception of generic base framework things). Which really isn't the tone I get from this answer.

Comment: I don't remember where I heard the term, I heard this as "Fail Fast and Fail Early"

Comment: @T.Sar Fail fast/early refers to detecting invalid states and inputs as soon as possible. It's an encouragement to *constrain* the system rather than let errors propagate until they manifest as a more severe or cryptic error.

Comment: @jpmc26 Hm.. that is interesting. I heard this in the context of when something on your system breaks (whatever it may be), don't hide or try to recover - let it blow up so you can generate proper trail to debug and fix things instead letting the system go in an unstable state. I wasn't aware of that other interpretation.

Comment: @Voo Call stack of a non-trivial application is often deep. Let's say there is a stack trace of total 30 calls, with 3 exception conversions. That's still only every 10th function needing to convert an exception.

Comment: Another reason to catch and re-throw would be to log internal state that could help debugging.

Comment: @Voo I think the term used to describe where to catch exceptions is the 'exception boundary', effectively the final `catch` block. For a library, this should not extend beyond its interface.

Comment: Log and rethrow is considered an [anti-pattern](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2139).
Regarding "catching if you no how to handle it": the question is not only what code belongs goes into the `catch` block, but also whether to execute the rest of teh `try`. So if the caller wants to avoid executing the code after a method in case of a failure, you need to tell about the failure, even if you catch and handle the exception.

Answer (score 22):

> What is wrong with this ?

Absolutely nothing.

> Now, that exception is bubbling up to MethodA, which handles it appropriately.

"handles it appropriately" is the important part.  That's the crux of Structured Exception Handling.

If your code can do something "useful" with an Exception, go for it.  If not, then let well alone.

> . . . why not catch the exception further up the chain instead of having try/catch blocks all the way down.

That's exactly what you *should* be doing. 
If you're reading code that has handler/rethrowers "all the way down", then you're [probably] reading some pretty poor code.

Sadly, some Developers just see catch blocks as "boiler-plate" code that they throw in (no pun intended) to every method they write, often because they don't really "get" Exception Handling and think they have to add something so that Exceptions don't "escape" and kill their program.

Part of the difficulty here is that, *most* of the time, this problem won't even get noticed, because Exceptions aren't being thrown all the time but, when they *are*, the program is going to waste an awful lot of time and effort gradually unpicking the call stack to get up to somewhere that actually does something useful with the Exception.

Comment: What's even worse is when the application catches the exception, and then logs it (where hopefully it won't just sit there forever) and attempts to continue on as usual, even when it really can't.

Comment: @SolomonUcko: Well, it depends. If for example you are writing a simple RPC server, and an unhandled exception bubbles all the way up to the main event loop, your only reasonable option is to log it, send an RPC error to the remote peer, and resume processing events. The other alternative is to kill the whole program, which will drive your SREs nuts when the server dies in production.

Comment: @Kevin In that case, there should be a single `catch` at the highest level possible that logs the error and returns an error response. Not `catch` blocks sprinkled everywhere. If you don't feel like listing every possible checked exception (in languages such as Java), just wrap it in a `RuntimeException` instead of logging it there, attempting to continue, and running into more errors or even vulnerabilities.

Comment: “Exceptions that run away”: In iOS development, there is often the attitude “if exception X happens, that is so bad, you don’t want to try to handle it but let it escape and crash the program”. Index-out-of-range for example is 99% a bug, 95% the index is often wrong but not out of range so you know there is an incorrect index much more often than the exception. Best to crash the app to give the developer a chance to fix the bug.

Answer (score 12):

You have to make a difference between Libraries and Applications.

## Libraries can throw uncaught exceptions freely

When you design a library, at some point you have to think about what can go wrong. Parameters could be in the wrong range or `null`, external resources could be unavailable, etc.

Your library most often will not have a way to deal with them in a *sensible* manner. The only sensible solution is to throw an appropriate Exception and let the developer of the Application deal with it.

## Applications should always at some point catch exceptions

When an Exception is caught, I like to categorize them as either **Errors** or **Fatal Errors**. A regular **Error** means that a single operation within my Application failed. For instance, an open document could not be saved, because the destination was not writable. The only sensible thing for the Application to do is inform the user that the operation could not be completed successfully, give human-readable information in regards to the problem and then let the user decide what to do next.

A **Fatal Error** is an error the main Application logic cannot recover from. For instance, if the graphics device driver crashes in a video game, there is no way for the Application to "gracefully" inform the user. In this case, a log file should be written and, if possible, the user should be informed in some way or another.

Even in such a severe case, the Application should handle this Exception in a meaningful way. This might include writing a Log file, sending a Crash Report, etc. There is no reason for the Application not to respond to the Exception in some way.

Comment: Indeed, if you have a library for something like disk write operations or, say, other hardware manipulation, you can end up in all sorts of unexpected events. What if a hard drive is yanked out during writing? What a CD drive shorts out while reading? That's outside your control and while you *could* do something (e.g., pretend it was successful), it's often a good practice to throw an exception to the library user and let them decide. Maybe a `HDDPluggedOutDuringWritingException` can be dealt with and is non-fatal for the application. The program can decide what to do with that.

Comment: @VLAZ What is fatal vs. non-fatal is something the application has to decide. The library should tell what happened. The Application has to decide how to react to it.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the pattern you describe is that method A will have no way of distinguishing between three scenarios:

1. Method B failed in an anticipated fashion.
2. Method C failed in a fashion not anticipated by method B, but while method B was performing an operation that could be safely abandoned.
3. Method C failed in a fashion not anticipated by method B, but while method B was performing an operation that placed things in a supposed-to-be-temporary incoherent state which B failed to clean up because of C's failure.

The only way method A will be able to distinguish those scenarios will be if the exception thrown from B includes information sufficient for that purpose, or if the stack unwinding for method B causes the object to be left in an *explicitly invalidated* state.  Unfortunately, most exception frameworks make both patterns awkward, forcing programmers to make "lesser evil" design decisions.

Comment: Scenario 2 and 3 are bugs in method B. Method A shouldn't try to fix those.

Comment: @Sjoerd: How is method B supposed to anticipate all of the ways in which method C might fail?

Comment: By well known patterns like performing all operations that might throw into temp variables, then with operations that cannot throw - e.g. swap - swap the old with the new state. Another pattern is defining operations that can be repeated safely, so you can retry the operation without fear of messing up. There are full books about writing 'exception safe code', so I can't tell you everything here.

Comment: This is a good point for not using exceptions at all (which would be an excellent decision imho). But I guess, it does not really answer the question, as the OP seems intent on using exceptions in the first place, and only asks *where* the catch should be.

Comment: @Sjoerd Method B becomes a lot easier to reason about if exceptions are forbidden by the language. Because in that case, you actually see all control flow paths through B, and you don't have to second guess which operators might be overloaded in a throwing fashion (C++) to avoid scenario 3. We are paying a lot in terms of code clarity and safety in order to be lazy about returning errors by "just" throwing exceptions. Because, in the end, error handling *is* a vital part of code.

Comment: @cmaster IMNSHO, code with exceptions is more clear than code with 'if (success)' on every second line. So I'm glad exceptions exists. And your point about overloading operators is a red herring - without overloading the code would be even less readable due to all the add(lhs, rhs, result)' calls, surrounded in if '(success)'.

Comment: @Sjoerd I agree to disagree... You are concerned about the clutter of error handling in the code, which is a valid concern. I am concerned about the explicitly visible control flow, which is another valid concern imho. We set different priorities, so we disagree. And that's fine with me :-)

Comment: @cmaster: It's a lot easier to reason about code if you ignore the possibility of operations failing for unpredictable reasons such as networks going down, media being "forcibly" ejected (e.g. someone unplugging a USB drive), etc.  And for some kinds of code that's a reasonable approach.  Some applications, however, have to deal with the possibility of operational failures that will unavoidably break some parts of the application but shouldn't kill the whole thing.